# no perder registro de personas pasando de un a menu a otro menu

Tags: java

estoy realizando un proyecto de una biblioteca, tengo un menú principal `

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Se declaran variables
    Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean salir = false;
    int opcion;

    while (!salir) {
        System.out.println("***Menú de Opciones para la Biblioteca**");
        System.out.println("1. Inicio de sesión administrativo");
        System.out.println("2. Inicio de sesión estudiantes regulares");
        System.out.println("3. Inicio de sesion para nuevos ingresos");
        System.out.println("4. Cerrar el programa");
        try {
            System.out.println("Elige una de estas opciones: ");
            opcion = sn.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Bienvenido estimado administrador de la biblioteca");
                    administracion adm=new administracion();
                    // Usuario: admin, Contraseña: biblioteca123
                    adm.verificarDatosAdmin();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    estudiantes est=new estudiantes();
                    est.menuEstu();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    nuevoIngreso estuIng=new nuevoIngreso();
                    estuIng.menuNuevoIng();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    
                    salir = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Solamente hay 3 opciones disponibles");
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException error) {
            System.out.println("Solamente se pueden introducir números");
            sn.next();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Se cerrara el programa");
}
```

y dentro de cada opción del switch, menos la del administrador tengo otro submenú por ejemplo, en la clase estudiantes tengo este menú:

```
 public void menuEstu() {
    boolean abandonar=false;
    int seleccionar;
    System.out.println("Bienvenido estudiante regular");
    while (!abandonar) {
       System.out.println("**Opciones estudiante regular**");
       System.out.println("1. Iniciar Sesion");
       System.out.println("2. Registrarse");
       System.out.println("3. Salir");
       try{
       System.out.println("Seleccione una opcion: ");
       seleccionar=scn.nextInt();
       switch (seleccionar) {
            case 1:
                verificarEstu();
                break;
            case 2:
                RegiEestudiantes();
                break;
            case 3:
                abandonar=true;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Solamente hay 3 opciones disponibles");
                break;
            }
        }catch(InputMismatchException Error) {
             System.out.println("Solamente se pueden introducir numeros");
             scn.next();
        }
    }
}
```

dentro de este submenú tengo las opciones de registrar estudiantes y el inicio de sesión para estos mismos:

```
 private void RegiEestudiantes() { 
    int romper=1;
    for (cont=cantEstu++; cont<estu.length; cont++) {
        estu[cont]=new estudiantes();
        System.out.println("Digite el nombre con el que se desea registrar: ");
        estu[cont].nombreEstu=scn.next();
        System.out.println("Digite el carnet con el que se desea registrar: ");
        estu[cont].carnetEstu=scn.next();
        // Se rompe el ciclo para que cada persona vaya registrandose una por una
        if (romper==1) {
            System.out.println("Se ha registrado con el nombre: " +estu[cont].nombreEstu+ " y con el carnet " +estu[cont].carnetEstu);
            setNombreEstu(estu[cont].nombreEstu);
            setCarnetEstu(estu[cont].carnetEstu);
            System.out.println("Se ha registrado el estudiante numero: "+cont);
            break;
        }
        
    }
   
}
 private void verificarEstu() {
    getNombreEstu();
    getCarnetEstu();
    boolean encontrar = false;
    for (cont=0; cont<estu.length; cont++) {
        if (nombreEstu.equals(estu[cont].nombreEstu) && carnetEstu.equals(estu[cont].carnetEstu)) {
            System.out.println("Bienvenido estimado: " +estu[cont].nombreEstu+ " cuyo carnet es: " +estu[cont].carnetEstu);
            encontrar=true;
            if (encontrar==true) {
                System.out.println("Introduzca el nombre del libro que desea pedir prestado: ");
                String verLibs=scn.next();
                break;
            }
        }else if(!nombreEstu.equals(estu[cont].nombreEstu) && !carnetEstu.equals(estu[cont].carnetEstu)){
             encontrar=false;
        }
    }
    // Si el estudiante no se encuentra se le muestra el siguiente mensaje
    if (encontrar==false) {
        System.out.println("El usuario no se encuentra en el sistema");
    }
}
```

ahora bien mi pregunta es, después de realizar el registro por ejemplo de 1 estudiante y volver al menú principal de la biblioteca, pierdo los datos de este mismo y tengo que volver a registrarlo, existe alguna forma de que no se pierdan estos datos, es una base de datos creada con el programa, por lo que no se guarda en MySQL ni nada por el estilo, al cerrar el programa se elimina, lo único que quiero comprobar es si es posible es que después de regresar al main y escoger la opción de estudiantes de nuevo, no se pierdan estos datos.

Comment: Cuando llames al método que necesites, pasa por parámetro los datos que has solicitado y si son varios datos guardalos en un arreglo y pasa el arreglo por parámetro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Observaciones**

Primero limpie un poco el código a mi estilo y tengo unas observaciones. La primera que es una buena practica llamar los objeto en Java con la primera letra mayúscula. Los programadores tienen que ser buenos en inventar nombres es una buena practica tener nombres de variables estratégico. La programación de objeto es usar cosas de la vida para resolver problemas, en este caso creo que es un error que el propio estudiante haga su menú. En mi solución cree una clase llamada Secretaria que ese objeto se va encargar de llevar el menú y el registro. Esta es la clase Secretaria.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Secretaria {

    public void menuEstu(Scanner scn) {
        boolean abandonar=false;
        int seleccionar;
        System.out.println("Bienvenido estudiante regular");
        while (!abandonar) {
           System.out.println("**Opciones estudiante regular**");
           System.out.println("1. Iniciar Sesion");
           System.out.println("2. Registrarse");
           System.out.println("3. Salir");
           try{
           System.out.println("Seleccione una opcion: ");
           seleccionar=scn.nextInt();
           switch (seleccionar) {
                case 1:
                    verificarEstu();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    RegiEestudiantes(scn);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    abandonar=true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Solamente hay 3 opciones disponibles");
                    break;
                }
            }catch(InputMismatchException Error) {
                 System.out.println("Solamente se pueden introducir numeros");
                 scn.next();
            }
        }

}
    private void RegiEestudiantes(Scanner scn) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
            String nombre;
            String codigo;
            
            System.out.println("Digite el nombre con el que se desea registrar: ");
            nombre = scn.next();
            
            System.out.println("Digite el carnet con el que se desea registrar: ");
            codigo = scn.next();
            
            Estudiantes.getTodos().add(new Estudiantes(nombre, codigo));
            Estudiantes.cont++;
            // Se rompe el ciclo para que cada persona vaya registrandose una por una
                System.out.println("Se ha registrado con el nombre: " + nombre + " y con el carnet " + codigo);
                System.out.println("Se ha registrado el estudiante numero: "+ Estudiantes.cont);
                
         
 }
    public void verificarDatosAdmin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    private void verificarEstu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

**Solución**

La forma que utilice fue utilizar un Vector que almacene el objeto Estudiantes y hacerlo estático  “static" para que se quede guardado en la ejecución del programa. Después en el menú hay otra función que es imprimir a los estudiantes para verificar si esta guardando los estudiantes correctamente. Aquí te dejo todo el código.

**Resto del código**

Clase Main

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Se declaran variables
        Scanner sn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Secretaria secretaria = new Secretaria();
        boolean salir = false;
        int opcion;

        while (!salir) {
            System.out.println("***Menú de Opciones para la Biblioteca**");
            System.out.println("1. Inicio de sesión administrativo");
            System.out.println("2. Inicio de sesión estudiantes regulares");
            System.out.println("3. Inicio de sesion para nuevos ingresos");
            System.out.println("4. Ver todo los estudiantes");
            System.out.println("5. Cerrar el programa");
            try {
                System.out.println("Elige una de estas opciones: ");
                opcion = sn.nextInt();
                switch (opcion) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Bienvenido estimado administrador de la biblioteca");
                        Administracion adm=new Administracion();
                        // Usuario: admin, Contraseña: biblioteca123
                        adm.verificarDatosAdmin();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        secretaria.menuEstu(sn);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        NuevoIngreso estuIng=new NuevoIngreso();
                        estuIng.menuNuevoIng();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println(Estudiantes.todoLosEstudiantes());
                        System.out.println("Intruduzca cualquier caracter con un enter: ");
                        sn.nextInt();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        salir = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Solamente hay 4 opciones disponibles");
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException error) {
                System.out.println("Solamente se pueden introducir números");
                sn.next();
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Se cerrara el programa");
    }

}
```

Clase Administracion

```
    public class Administracion {

    public void verificarDatosAdmin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Clase Estudiantes

```
    import java.util.Vector;

public class Estudiantes {
    
    private String nombreEst;
    private String codigoEst;
    
    public static int cont = 0;
    public static Vector<Estudiantes> todos = new Vector<Estudiantes>();
    
    public Estudiantes(String _nombreEst, String _codigoEst) {
        setNombre(_nombreEst);
        setCodigoEst(_codigoEst);
    }
    
    public static Vector<Estudiantes> getTodos() {
        return todos;
    }

    public static void setTodos(Vector<Estudiantes> todos) {
        Estudiantes.todos = todos;
    }


    public void setNombre(String _nombreEst) {
        nombreEst = _nombreEst;
    }
    
    public String getNombres() {
        return nombreEst;
    }
    
    public void setCodigoEst(String _codigoEst) {
        codigoEst = _codigoEst;
    }
    
    public String getCodigoEst() {
        return codigoEst;
    }

    public static String todoLosEstudiantes() {
        int numeroDeEstudiantes = 0;
        String todoLosEstudiantes = "";
        
        for(int i = 0; i < Estudiantes.getTodos().size(); i++) {
            numeroDeEstudiantes++;
            todoLosEstudiantes +=  "Nombre del estudiante: " + Estudiantes.getTodos().get(i).getNombres() + "\n"
                                +  "El codigo del estudiante: " + Estudiantes.getTodos().get(i).getCodigoEst() + "\n"
                                +  "Numero de estudiantes: " + numeroDeEstudiantes;
        }
        return todoLosEstudiantes;
    }
            
}
```

Clase NuevoIngreso

```
    public class NuevoIngreso {

    public void menuNuevoIng() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

Clase Secretaría

```
    import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Secretaria {

    public void menuEstu(Scanner scn) {
        boolean abandonar=false;
        int seleccionar;
        System.out.println("Bienvenido estudiante regular");
        while (!abandonar) {
           System.out.println("**Opciones estudiante regular**");
           System.out.println("1. Iniciar Sesion");
           System.out.println("2. Registrarse");
           System.out.println("3. Salir");
           try{
           System.out.println("Seleccione una opcion: ");
           seleccionar=scn.nextInt();
           switch (seleccionar) {
                case 1:
                    verificarEstu();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    RegiEestudiantes(scn);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    abandonar=true;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Solamente hay 3 opciones disponibles");
                    break;
                }
            }catch(InputMismatchException Error) {
                 System.out.println("Solamente se pueden introducir numeros");
                 scn.next();
            }
        }

}
    private void RegiEestudiantes(Scanner scn) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
            String nombre;
            String codigo;
            
            System.out.println("Digite el nombre con el que se desea registrar: ");
            nombre = scn.next();
            
            System.out.println("Digite el carnet con el que se desea registrar: ");
            codigo = scn.next();
            
            Estudiantes.getTodos().add(new Estudiantes(nombre, codigo));
            Estudiantes.cont++;
            // Se rompe el ciclo para que cada persona vaya registrandose una por una
                System.out.println("Se ha registrado con el nombre: " + nombre + " y con el carnet " + codigo);
                System.out.println("Se ha registrado el estudiante numero: "+ Estudiantes.cont);
                
         
 }
    public void verificarDatosAdmin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
    private void verificarEstu() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```